# python no me deja leer un archivo json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

estoy haciendo un pequeño bot en discord y en una parte pido unos datos de otra API(localbitcoin) que me los da en formato json

le doy print a la variable que almacena el json para que vean q si es un .json
[image: le doy print al valor de la variable que almacena el json para que vean que si es .json]

luego trato de abrir ese archivo como se ve a continuación

```
import discord 
from lbcapi3 import api
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import json

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="This a helper 
bot")

hmac_key = 'aqui van unas claves pero las quite para hacer el 
capture'
hmac_secret = 'aqui van unas claves pero las quite para hacer el 
capture'

conn = api.hmac(hmac_key, hmac_secret)

#Aca recibo el json
dolar_json = conn.call('GET', '/api/equation/USD_in_VES').json()

#luego lo intento leer
dolarfinal = json.loads(dolar_json)

#aqui lo imprimo
print(dolarfinal['data'])
```

y me da el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano!

Comment: No es dolar_json ya un dict? (porque el call del rest lo concatenas con un .json)

Comment: En teoría si entiendo bien tú código, estás intentando leer un diccionario que  ya tienes en una variable. Simplemente deberías de hacer print de dolar_json para ver el diccionario. De todas formas te dejo la respuesta del error que te está ocurriendo en concreto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es la primera pregunta relacionada con JSON en la que observo una confusión con respecto a lo que JSON es en realidad. De modo que, aunque esto responde mucho más de lo que preguntas, puede ayudarte a aclarar las ideas, y puede servirme a mi como "respuesta canónica" hacia la que puedo redirigir consultas similares.

## JSON es un string

JSON no es más que el nombre para un formato particular de cadena de caracteres. El JSON típicamente lo recibes como respuesta a una petición HTTP, o también puede ser que lo leas de un fichero. En ambos casos lo que tienes es una *cadena* (`str` en python).

#### Estructura del JSON

Lo que ocurre es que esta cadena tiene una **estructura** concreta, que viene del mundo JavaScript. El aspecto es muy similar al de un diccionario o una lista Python, pero hay diferencias. JSON no es Python.

De acuerdo con esta estructura, lo que hay dentro de esa cadena es una colección de datos organizados, que puede ser de uno de los siguientes tipos:

- Numérico (en JSON no hay diferencia entre entero o flotante, ambos son números). Un dato numérico se representa por ejemplo así: `15` o así `3.1415`
- Cadena. Una cadena JSON va delimitada por comillas dobles, por ejemplo `"Esta"`. No es válido usar comillas simples como usa Python.
- Booleano. Un booleano JSON sólo puede tomar los valores `true` o `false` (no van entre comillas pues en ese caso serían de tipo cadena, y observa las minúsculas, son importantes, `False` o `True` como usa Python serían un error dentro de una cadena JSON)
- Valor nulo. En JSON se representa por `null` (sin comillas). Python en cambio usa `None`, cuidado.
- Lista. Una lista comienza por `[` y termina por `]` y contiene separados por comas datos de cualquiera de los tipos que estamos describiendo (por tanto, otra lista también sería válida, o un objeto). La sintaxis por tanto es como en Python.
- Objeto. Un objeto JSON comienza por `{`  y termina por `}` y contiene, separadas por comas, una serie de parejas clave-valor, estando separadas por dos puntos la clave del valor. La clave ha de ser de tipo cadena (es decir, ha de ir entre comillas dobles), y el valor puede ser cualquiera de los tipos aquí descritos (por tanto, una lista, un entero, una cadena,... e incluso otro objeto anidado). La sintaxis es como la de un diccionario Python, pero con la restricción (que python no tiene) de que todas las claves han de ser de tipo cadena, y los valores sólo de uno de los tipos aquí explicados.

En ocasiones he leido que, para que sea JSON válido, el dato "principal" ha de ser de tipo objeto, dentro del que pueden aparecer otros datos de otros tipos. En la práctica he visto que esto no suele respetarse y no parece causar problemas. Por tanto una respuesta JSON podría contener también una lista como "dato principal".

#### Ejemplo de JSON válido

```
{
  "numeros": [ 1, 2, 3.5, 4 ],
  "usuario": {
     "nombre": "Manolo",
     "apellidos": "López",
     "email": null,
     "es_admin": false
     }
}
```

## JSON no es un diccionario Python

Como hemos dicho, JSON es una cadena, y el contenido de esa cadena se parece mucho a un diccionario Python, pero no lo es. Por tanto para poder usar JSON desde python hay que *parsearlo*, lo que significa procesar esa cadena para ir convirtiendo sus contenidos a los tipos de datos Python.

La forma típica de hacer esto es usar el módulo `json`, por ejemplo:

```
cadena_json = """
{
  "numeros": [ 1, 2, 3.5, 4 ],
  "usuario": {
     "nombre": "Manolo",
     "apellidos": "López",
     "email": null,
     "es_admin": false
     }
}
"""

import json
datos = json.loads(cadena_json)
```

El resultado (variable `datos`) sí será ahora un diccionario python, con la misma estructura que vemos en el JSON. Por tanto podremos acceder a `datos["numeros"]` (y eso será una lista, por lo que podremos acceder a `datos["numeros"][0]`), o podemos acceder a `datos["usuario"]["es_admin"]`, que nos devolverá el booleano python `False`.

De hecho, si imprimes `datos` verás el resultado de la conversión, que es *muy similar* al JSON de entrada pero tiene diferencias:

```
print(datos)

---

{'numeros': [1, 2, 3.5, 4],
 'usuario': {'apellidos': 'López',
             'email': None,
             'es_admin': False,
             'nombre': 'Manolo'}}
```

Observa las diferencias:

- Python ha elegido, a la hora de convertir `datos` en cadena para imprimirlo, usar el `'` como delimitador de cadenas, en vez de `"`. Las claves del diccionario son `'numeros'`, en vez de `"numeros"`. Esto no es válido en JSON
- El valor del email es `None` en vez de `null`
- El valor del booleano es `False` en vez de `false`

Por tanto, si tienes datos Python y quieres convertirlos en una cadena que sea JSON válido, no debes usar `str(datos)`, sino `json.dumps(datos)`, que hace las transformaciones necesarias para garantizar que el resultado sea JSON válido.

#### JSON, Python y las bibliotecas de red

Ya que JSON se usa muy a menudo en el mundo de las APIS, es frecuente que cuando haces una petición a una WEB te responda con JSON. Lo que recibe Python en ese caso es una cadena (¿he dicho ya que JSON no es más que una cadena?) Pero entre las cabeceras de la respuesta vendrá una que dice que su formato es JSON (cabecera `Content-Type: application/json`). Muchas bibliotecas que manejan HTTP (como por ejemplo la biblioteca `requests`) te dan funciones que te permiten obtener, bien la cadena recibida (el JSON propiamente dicho) o bien el resultado de *parsearlo* y convertirlo en datos Python.

Por ejemplo usando `rquests`, si `r` es la variable que guarda la respuesta a la petición HTTP, mediante `r.content` puedes acceder a la cadena "pura" (el JSON propiamente dicho). Usando en cambio `r.json()` llamas a la función que lo *parsea* y te lo devuelve como datos Python.

## Tu caso

Estás usando `libcapi3`, la cual por debajo usa la biblioteca `requests`. Cuando llamas a `conn.call()`, el objeto retornado es una respuesta HTTP, de la cual puedes obtener directamente el texto recibido (`.content`), o si ese texto es una cadena JSON válida, el resultado de *parsearla* a tipo de datos python (`.json()`).

En tu caso llamas a `.json()`, por lo que lo que obtienes será ya un diccionario Python. Por eso no puedes pasarselo luego a `json.loads()`, pues ese espera una cadena.

Por tanto, o lees la respuesta como cadena para parsearla tú mismo luego:

```
dolar_json = conn.call('GET', '/api/equation/USD_in_VES').content
dolarfinal = json.loads(dolar_json)
```

O la lees ya parseada, con lo que el resultado ya es lo que llamas `dolarfinal` (y no necesitas importar la biblioteca `json`).

```
dolarfinal = conn.call('GET', '/api/equation/USD_in_VES').json()
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, bien elaborada!

Comment: Estupenda respuesta. Respecto a lo de _JSON válido_, puede ser tanto un objeto como una lista. Las claves de un objeto no tienen orden; mientras que una lista son elementos ordenados.

Sí que es recomendable que una API devuelva un objeto para incluir _metainformación_. Por ejemplo, si pides 500 elementos y sólo había 200, para tener alguna confirmación de que has leído todos los que había.

Comment: en serio muchas gracias me ha servido mucho tu respuesta

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Aclara varios asuntos respecto a lo que es y no es JSON.